# C++: would universal use of shared_ptr<> be equivalent to a gc?

Tags: java, c++, garbage-collection, smart-pointers

This is just an academic question (I would never do this in real code):

**If I were to use shared_ptr<> universally in my code, would the behavior be equivalent to a gc-collected language like Java?**

If not, how would the behavior be different from a gc-embedded language?  Which C++ construct would yield equivalent behavior compared to a gc-embedded language?

Note: In real coding, I strongly prefer the use of RAII and strict ownership over the use of any smart pointers.  I also know that other less-generic pointers, unique_ptr<> would be more efficient.  This question is just a query into smart-pointer equivalence.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, there'd be a couple of important differences:

- You would get a memory leak any time you have a cyclic reference. A garbage collector can handle cycles, ref-counting can't.
- You would avoid any stalls or pauses because no garbage collection ever occurs. On the other hand, you'd likely spend more total CPU time cleaning up resources, because the amortized cost of an occasional garbage collection is pretty low, and ref-counting can be relatively expensive if you do it on everything.

Obviously the first point is the killer. If you did this, many of your resources wouldn't get freed, and you'd leak memory and your app just wouldn't behave very well.

> Which C++ construct would yield equivalent behavior compared to a gc-embedded language?

None. C++ doesn't have a garbage collector because there's no way to implement a correct, reliable one. (Yes, I'm aware of Boehm's GC, and it's a good approximation, but it's conservative, and doesn't detect all references, only the ones it can be 100% sure of. There is no way, in a general C++ program, to implement a garbage collector that Just Works(tm))

Comment: is shared_ptr thread safe? then it got to be quite expensive for counter increment

Comment: Yes on both counts. The increments/decrements are implemented using atomic operations, so there is some overhead there because each one has to lock the memory bus.

Comment: Very interesting!  So by your measure, is the Java gc correct but not so reliable?  I am not trying to troll - just trying to better understand current state of gc technology.

Comment: The Java GC is correct and reliable. It is able to find and release *any* unreferenced object. (it may still stall your program for a moment while performing a collection, and it prevents you from using RAII and makes it harder to control the lifetime of your resources than in C++, but as a GC it gets the job done)

Comment: Do you have any referencs for `On the other hand, you'd likely spend more total CPU time cleaning up resources`. Seems rather a bold claim.

Comment: @LokiAstari: I don't have references for that, but I share the same gut feeling. In Java the cost of allocation is about 7 assembly instructions, while allocating in C++ is much higher. For each new reference there is a count increment, for each leaving reference a decrement, while in a GC world only those references that are alive at the time of collection need to be tracked. The cost of collecting dead objects is nothing, only alive objects are processed. Of course, the cost there is higher in a generational GC, as they *move* the objects around...

Comment: @David Rodríguez: I find `7 assembly instructions` instructions hard to swallow. Maybe `7 Byte Code instructions`. To perform GC the memory management sub-system needs to maintain records in the same way that a shared pointer does. I am not going to claim that shared pointer is faster (but intuitively (my gut) feels like they are in the same order of magnitude).

Comment: @LokiAstari: do the math. With ref-counting you need an atomic (read: expensive) memory access every time you add or remove a reference. That adds up. With GC, your code can normally run with zero overhead, and then once every blue moon, it is pause, and the graph of live objects is traverse (or commonly, a small subset of it, the objects in generation 0).

Comment: And no, a sane (modern) GC does not need to maintain records like that *at all*. It needs to know the type of each object, which is basically just a vptr in each object (which most GC'ed language would have had to have *anyway*), and that's all. And of course, that pointer is set at object creation, it's not something that needs to be maintained. Modern GC's really are very clever. And any book on the subject will do the math for you, if you're interested.

Comment: @jalf: An argument based on `do the maths` is not that convincing. So I'll assume that you have only intuited that answer and have no real numbers to back it up.

Comment: @LokiAstari: assume what you like. ;) I personally find maths quite convincing, and we were pounded through them some years ago in my advanced compilers course at uni. If you really want, I'll look through my books to find the exact numbers later.

Comment: @jalf: A reference to a paper will do. Maths is very convincing unfortunately I see none here just wind.

Comment: Ok, I tried to fit in a description of how a modern generational GC works, but I can't cram it into these comments. If you *actually* want to know, look it up. In short, the GC normally only visits small and young live (reachable) objects, and each of these is typically moved/compacted (which is a plain memcpy), and it only does this a fixed number of times for each object before it's upgraded to gen1 where it's visited much more rarely. The amortized number of reads/writes per object is fairly small, and it doesn't depend on atomic ops like ref-counting does

Comment: @LokiAstari It's covered in any reasonable book on compiler implementation. The one we used was Modern Compiler Implementation in ML, by A. Appel. Haven't checked the dragon book, but would expect it to describe this as well. Otherwise, a quick google for papers on generational garbage collection should tell you what you want to know. And just to be clear, I'm only talking about amortized cost. It can be a huge disadvantage that this cost is so "clumped together", and is incurred all at once at intervals, where with ref-counting the cost is paid gradually making it less noticeable

Comment: @Jalf: I have read many papers on the topic. I want to know where you are getting your `bold claims` from. I know GC are good and the cost of shared pointers. But nothing I have read would allow me to make quite so bold claim. And I would have liked to read the paper that provided that kind of insight. So I assume you had read something specific. But now it seems otherwise.

Comment: @LokiAstari As of the cost of allocation for a generational GC, the important bit is that the allocator does not track holes. It allocates contiguous memory irrespective of the type being allocated, so it only needs to maintain a pointer to the first free address in the generation (`heapStart`). `new` (simplistic) is just getting the pointer, adding the size of the object and storing it as the new `heapStart` and returning the old pointer. The *real* `new` checks first (pointer difference + comparison) if there is enough space in this heap, and if not calls the GC.

Comment: This is an old [paper](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp01274/index.html) on memory allocation and GC in Java, it is old and the GC have evolved a bit, but it gives the code of the allocator function. Note that I have bluntly ignored the cost of synchronization as that is common to both `malloc` and Java, and it can be reduced by keeping per-thread heaps (much simpler in Java than in C/C++)

Comment: @David Rodríguez: Thanks. I see how you can get 7 instructions from that. But a lot of the details have been pushed to the GC in that model of looking at it. And as always the devil is in the detail.

Comment: @LokiAstari Programming should be done *knowing* where the costs come from. For example, applications where there is a whole lot of dynamic allocations and deallocations will be much more efficient in a GC environment, as the cost of GC is proportional to the set of alive objects, that is, performing 1 or 1000 `new` inside a tight loop will only have the impact of the allocations if the GC runs when those references have been dropped. Those 1000 objects created and forgotten will not have any impact on the peformance of GC, while they would have impacted a lot without GC.

Comment: There is also the classic 1992 SP&E paper - "The Measured Cost of Conservative Garbage Collection" by Benjamin Zorn, where he shows empirically that for some large-scale applications the cost of manual storage management in C is *comparable* with the cost of storage management with a slow old-fashioned conservative garbage collector.  http://www.cs.colorado.edu/department/publications/reports/docs/CU-CS-573-92.pdf

Answer (score 4):

@jalf says this in his answer:

> You would avoid any stalls or pauses because no garbage collection ever occurs.

While smart pointers (or any reference counting scheme) have no pause while garbage collection occurs, you *can* get a pause if you null the last external pointer to a large data structure, and trigger a cascade of reference count adjustments and finalizations for each node in the data structure.  While a smart smart-pointer implementation could ameliorate this, you'd be sacrificing immediate reclamation ... which some people claim is an advantage of smart pointers.

Also, there is an overhead of a few instructions each time you assign to a smart pointer-typed variable, and the overheads of allocating an object is greater.

Answer (score 2):

Garbage collection happens whenever the GC decides that it should. `shared_ptr`s are not collected. An object managed by a `shared_ptr` will only *ever* be destroyed in the destructor of a `shared_ptr`. And therefore, you know exactly when memory can and can *not* be freed.

You still have control over when memory goes away with `shared_ptr`. You don't have that with a garbage collector (outside of coarse-grained commands like turning it on/off or modifying it's behavior a bit).

Answer (score 2):

The main difference is that reference counting alone can't free circular data structures.

Many cases of such structures can nevertheless be handled by using `weak_ptr` appropriately, and some cases can be handled by delegating cleanup responsibility to a collection object.

However, the most frivolous spaghetti structures, if you want them (e.g. for math), can't have automated cleanup implemented by reference counting alone, because there will be circular sub-structures.

Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 0):

Its worth noting that a shared ptr is much larger that a Java reference.  Generally this won't matter but some situations it might.

In Java 6, 64-bit JVMs still use 32-bit references access up to 32 GB of heap (it can do this because objects are on 8 byte boundaries)  However a shared ptr uses two pointers (each 8 bytes in a 64-bit applications), the second pointer references an object which contains the counter. On libgcc it allocates 32-byte minimum to any malloc/new object. In total the shared pointer could be using 48 bytes which is relatively larger than 4 bytes. 44 bytes is not going to make a difference, but it could if you have lots of these.